# NameNode Does Not Start with start-all.sh

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

The NameNode does not start after `stop-all.sh` with `start-all.sh`. I try `hadoop namenode -format` and `hadoop-daemon.sh` start namenode then everything ok. However my data is lost in HDFS.

I do not want data loss. This result, `hadoop namenode -format` command is not want my path to a solution. How can I start the NameNode with `start-all.sh` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hadoop.temp.dir`

temp = should be "tmp"  =>  `hadoop.tmp.dir`

I missed only "e".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `stop-all.sh` with `start-all.sh` are deprecated. Use `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` instead of `start-all.sh`. Same with `stop-all.sh`(it already says so)

secondly, `hadoop namenode -format` formats your HDFS and should therefore be used only once, at the time of installation.

Hadoop by default sets the property of `hadoop.tmp.dir` to a directory in `/tmp`, where the files are deleted after every restart. Set the `hadoop.tmp.dir` property in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop/core-site.xml`, to some place where the files are not usually deleted. Run the `hadoop namenode -format` (actually it is `hdfs namenode -format`, this one is also deprecated.) one last time and start the daemons.

PS: If you can post the log file or the terminal screenshot of the error, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I try that but it was not successful:
How to attacted log file?

Comment: <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:10001</value>
</property>
<property>
         <name>hadoop.temp.dir</name>
         <value>/home/can/Desktop/myHadoopTmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>

Comment: copy the output of the `start-all.sh` run and paste it in http://pastebin.com/ and post the link in the question

Comment: Otherwise you can find the logs in your logs directory